# Logic app- how to retrieve json data from dynamic property name

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Here's my json - Here I want to retrieve json content from "Property - Dynamic content". Where, dynamic content part might vary for every json request. How do I filter this by a dynamic name?

```
{
  "Attributes": 
  {
    "Property1": {
      "Data1": {
        "Value": "50"
  }
},
"Property2": {
  "Data2": {
    "Value": "50"
  }
},
"Property - Dynamic content": {
  "Data3": {
    "Value": "50"
  },
  "Data4": {
    "Value": "50"
  }
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get what I need using inline code - javascript - If anyone else is looking for the same - here it is - This will give json from Property - dynamic content element.

var data = Object.keys(workflowContext.trigger.outputs.body.Attributes);

var key = data.filter(s => s.includes('Property')).toString(); // to get element -  Property - dynamic content

return workflowContext.trigger.outputs.body.Attributes[key];

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement, please refer to my logic app below:

**1.** I initialized a variable and store the json same with yours to simulate your situation.

[image]

**2.** Then use "[Parse JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action)".

[image]

Please notice the schema of "**Parse JSON**" show as:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "Attributes": {
            "properties": {
                "Property - Dynamic content": {
                    "type": [
                        "object",
                        "array"
                    ]
                },
                "Property1": {
                    "properties": {
                        "Data1": {
                            "properties": {
                                "Value": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            },
                            "type": "object"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                },
                "Property2": {
                    "properties": {
                        "Data2": {
                            "properties": {
                                "Value": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            },
                            "type": "object"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

**Please pay attention** to the `type` of `Property - Dynamic content` in schema above. Since the content of `Property - Dynamic content` is either "object" or "array", so I set both "object" and "array" as the `type` of `Property - Dynamic content`.

**3.** Then I initialized a variable named "result" to get the value which you want.
[image]

As we use both type "object" and "array" in the schema for `Property - Dynamic content`, so you may not find it in the "Dynamic content" selection. You can input its value by expression as the screenshot above. The whole expression is: `body('Parse_JSON')?['Attributes']?['Property - Dynamic content']`

Comment: Here, the dynamic content part can be anything like 'Property - Name' or 'Property - Something'. If I refer expression like this - body('Parse_JSON')?['Attributes']?['Property - Dynamic content'], Then, its static.. I need to refer that part as a variable or something

Comment: Hi @Mm77 The `Property - Name` can also be dynamic. For example, initialize a variable `var1` like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0wtI.png) and set its value with anything you want. Then we just need to change the expression to `body('Parse_JSON')?['Attributes']?[variables('var1')]`. Anyway, you have solved the problem, that's great :)