# how to get a value of a json http response in azure logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to get "id" value set to a variable by parsing the below output sample. The REST API call will return multiple values as shown below and I'm interested in only getting the "id" value for the particular name that users has provided/set as input in the workflow earlier either by a parameter value or by initializing a variable. How do I do this value extraction in azure logic app?

Any help much appreciated.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "xyz-List",
    "data": {
      "urls": [
        "*.test1.com",
        "*.test2.com"
      ],
      "type": "exact"
    },
    "modify_by": "admin@xyz.com",
    "modify_time": "2022-06-29T21:05:27.000Z",
    "modify_type": "Created",
    "pending": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "abc-List",
    "data": {
      "urls": [
        "www.mytesting.com"
      ],
      "type": "exact"
    },
    "modify_by": "admin@xyz.com",
    "modify_time": "2022-06-29T21:05:27.000Z",
    "modify_type": "Created",
    "pending": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "azure-list",
    "data": {
      "type": "exact",
      "urls": [
        "www.xyz.com",
        "www.azure-test.com"
      ],
      "json_version": 2
    },
    "modify_by": "admin@xyz.com",
    "modify_time": "2022-09-26T01:25:20.000Z",
    "modify_type": "Edited",
    "pending": 0
  }
]
```

Comment: take a look on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64254661/1384539

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced from my end and could able to make it work by parsing your REST API call value. To iterate through the Parsed JSON I have used a for-each loop and extracted the `Id` using the below expression and set its value to a variable.

```
@items('For_each')['id']
```

Below is the complete flow of my logic app

[image]

**RESULTS:**

[image]

To reproduce the same in your logic app you can use the below code view that worked for me.

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "data": {
                            "type": "exact",
                            "urls": [
                                "*.test1.com",
                                "*.test2.com"
                            ]
                        },
                        "id": 1,
                        "modify_by": "admin@xyz.com",
                        "modify_time": "2022-06-29T21:05:27.000Z",
                        "modify_type": "Created",
                        "name": "xyz-List",
                        "pending": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "data": {
                            "type": "exact",
                            "urls": [
                                "www.mytesting.com"
                            ]
                        },
                        "id": 2,
                        "modify_by": "admin@xyz.com",
                        "modify_time": "2022-06-29T21:05:27.000Z",
                        "modify_type": "Created",
                        "name": "abc-List",
                        "pending": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "data": {
                            "json_version": 2,
                            "type": "exact",
                            "urls": [
                                "www.xyz.com",
                                "www.azure-test.com"
                            ]
                        },
                        "id": 3,
                        "modify_by": "admin@xyz.com",
                        "modify_time": "2022-09-26T01:25:20.000Z",
                        "modify_type": "Edited",
                        "name": "azure-list",
                        "pending": 0
                    }
                ],
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Set_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "Id",
                            "value": "@items('For_each')['id']"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "SetVariable"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Parse_JSON')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Id",
                            "type": "integer"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@outputs('Compose')",
                    "schema": {
                        "items": {
                            "properties": {
                                "data": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "type": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "urls": {
                                            "items": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "type": "array"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "type": "object"
                                },
                                "id": {
                                    "type": "integer"
                                },
                                "modify_by": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "modify_time": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "modify_type": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "name": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "pending": {
                                    "type": "integer"
                                }
                            },
                            "required": [
                                "id",
                                "name",
                                "data",
                                "modify_by",
                                "modify_time",
                                "modify_type",
                                "pending"
                            ],
                            "type": "object"
                        },
                        "type": "array"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: thank you for going above and beyond to help with this, his is exactly what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

Load this into your tenant.  You can use basic expressions with a condition to get your result ...

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_Each_Array_Item": {
                "actions": {
                    "Condition": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Set_ID": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "ID",
                                    "value": "@item()['id']"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "SetVariable"
                            }
                        },
                        "expression": {
                            "and": [
                                {
                                    "equals": [
                                        "@item()['name']",
                                        "abc-List"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "If"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@variables('Array Data')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_ID": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_Array_Data": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Array Data",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": [
                                {
                                    "data": {
                                        "type": "exact",
                                        "urls": [
                                            "*.test1.com",
                                            "*.test2.com"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "id": 1,
                                    "modify_by": "admin@xyz.com",
                                    "modify_time": "2022-06-29T21:05:27.000Z",
                                    "modify_type": "Created",
                                    "name": "xyz-List",
                                    "pending": 0
                                },
                                {
                                    "data": {
                                        "type": "exact",
                                        "urls": [
                                            "www.mytesting.com"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "id": 2,
                                    "modify_by": "admin@xyz.com",
                                    "modify_time": "2022-06-29T21:05:27.000Z",
                                    "modify_type": "Created",
                                    "name": "abc-List",
                                    "pending": 0
                                },
                                {
                                    "data": {
                                        "json_version": 2,
                                        "type": "exact",
                                        "urls": [
                                            "www.xyz.com",
                                            "www.azure-test.com"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "id": 3,
                                    "modify_by": "admin@xyz.com",
                                    "modify_time": "2022-09-26T01:25:20.000Z",
                                    "modify_type": "Edited",
                                    "name": "azure-list",
                                    "pending": 0
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_ID": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "ID",
                            "type": "integer"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Array_Data": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "ParameterTest1": {
                "defaultValue": "\"\"",
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "method": "GET",
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

My example looks for the name `abc-List` and if it finds it, it sets the `ID` variable to be the associated ID of that record it found the name against.

[image: Flow]

Comment: thank you. I upvoted it but can't seems to accept both. Appreciate you taking the time and helping with the answer.